# Jquery Increment/Decrement Price Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my code I don't wonder why this isn't working ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
var increment2=0;
$('.checkbox').live('change', function() {
    $('.number').html( '(' + (increment2 += this.checked ? 1 : -1) + ')');             
})
</script> 
<td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="cb" value="1"> 1 </td>
<div class="number">
hello
</div>
```

even this code doesn't work

```
var increment2=0; 
        $('.checkbox').live('click', function() { 
            if ($(this).attr('checked') === 'checked') {
                increment2+=10;                 
            } else {
                increment2-=10;
            }
            $('.number').html( '( hello ' + increment2 + ')');             
    })
```

Comment: What outdated version of jQuery are you using that `live` is still valid? live has been deprecated and removed from jQuery for a long time.

Comment: Are there errors in the console?

Comment: none. even this code doesnt work... is anyone got an idea var increment2=0; 
        $('.checkbox').live('click', function() { 
            if ($(this).attr('checked') === 'checked') {
                increment2+=10;                 
            } else {
                increment2-=10;
            }
            $('.number').html( '( hello ' + increment2 + ')');             
    })

Comment: So what outdated version of jQuery are you using. I used it with 1.3 and your orginal code ran.

Comment: what if I am using the latest version. How can I solve that?

Comment: As I told you in my previous comment, as of jQuery 1.7, the `live` method is deprecated. Use `on`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when I use a really old version of jQuery your code runs fine.

```js
var increment2=0;
$('.checkbox').live('change', function() {
    $('.number').html( '(' + (increment2 += this.checked ? 1 : -1) + ')');             
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="cb" value="1"> 1 </td>
<div class="number">
hello
</div>
```

so my guess is you are using a modern version of jQuery that does not support `live`. So you need to use `on` with event delegation.

```js
var increment2=0;
$(document).on("change", ".checkbox", function() {
    $('.number').html( '(' + (increment2 += this.checked ? 1 : -1) + ')');             
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="cb" value="1"> 1 </td>
<div class="number">
hello
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 1.7, the `live` method is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

If you are using a more recent version, you should use `on`. And be sure to specify this event handling to execute [when the DOM is fully loaded](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).

```
var increment2=0;
$(function() { // $.ready
    $('.checkbox').on('change', function() {
        $('.number').html( '(' + (increment2 += this.checked ? 1 : -1) + ')');
    });
});
```